# Emitting node.js views and scripts as snippets

Tags: node.js, code-snippets

I have built a node.js app for which i would like to realize "snippets" to be included in external web applications. It means that i must create some javascript scripts to be included and called from external apps that call a node.js view and its scripts/css .

Does node.js provide a way to do it natively or do i have to create the script that embeds the view and the related client libraries?

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm not sure I understand the question. Does node.js app means a node http server? you say you must create some scripts, if you could elaborate on that it would be great :)

Answer (score 3):

enable cross-origin resource sharing:

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a specification that enables truly open access across domain-boundaries. If you serve public content, please consider using CORS to open it up for universal JavaScript/browser access.

Must read: http://enable-cors.org/#how-expressJS

Important stuff:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like components might be your answer:

https://github.com/component/component

http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/27984551477/components

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question - You want to display an html-like snippet on a different site.

- One way of doing it is to provide an API, but it will probably be a
  JSON API, and the other site will have to display it on its own
  (somebody already noted CORS is needed for this). You could just serve a JSON with html in it (though you need to make sure the other app doesn't escape it)
- You could have your server serve an image (like they do in travis CI), but then the other site will show it as an image (copy paste the text won't be possible)
- You could use [Iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp), serving an html to this other site.

There's the possibility you meant something totally different, like reusing your server an client code - in that case I recommend http://browserify.org, or the already mentioned component.js.